# R adding 10min to a Date Time

Tags: r

I have a date time and I would like to add 10 mins to it.
eg "2018-08-09 20:00:00 BST"+10min would be "2018-08-09 20:10:00 BST"
I tried:

```
date1 <- "2018-08-09 20:00:00 BST"
date2 <- as.POSIXct(date1 , format="%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
date3 <-date2+10
date3
```

but this did not work.

Comment: Notice that `date2` is NA. The problem is that your format does not match your input data.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding a numeric value is in seconds, so you can just multiply by 60. Also you can set timezone with `tz` argument to `as.POSIXct`, but it couldn't find `"BST"`

```
    date1 <- "2018-08-09 20:00:00 BST"
    date2 <- as.POSIXct(date1 , format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    date3 <-date2+10*60
    date3 

[1] "2018-08-09 20:10:00 PDT"
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you for your help